# Installing script: check if the installation directory is in the user's path

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a `setup.py` to install some command-line tools that accompany
 my package:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
  ...
  scripts = ['bin/foo'],
  ...
)
```

which is able to 'install' my script just fine.

The question is now, suppose that Python uses a location that is not yet in the user's `PATH`, for example by

```
python -m pip install foo --user
```

How can I alert the user to add this location? When I recently installed `twine` this way, I got a notification along the lines of "The path `'./.local/bin'` is not in the user's PATH, consider adding it in the appropriate way."

Comment: Why not steal [some code from pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/52cf26e5cb015c4dc408693d599c78592823d404/src/pip/_internal/wheel.py#L146)? [The license](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/LICENSE.txt) is MIT, quite a permissive one.

Comment: @phd That's a fair idea, thanks!